# How to authorize an API Gateway Endpoint for users logged in with cognito and users not logged in

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

My question is about how I should secure an API Gateway Endpoint.

I'm currently playing around with a web app, and I'm using API Gateway and AWS cognito.

I'm using aws cognito to manage users that sign up.

However, not all endpoints require a user to be signedup/loggedin to get access to it. There are some endpoints that will return different payloads depending on whether the user is signedup/loggedin.
For example if a user is signed in then they will see there message inbox on the page, however if the user is not signed in they will just see the content of the page.  Similar to how twitter or facebook does it.

What is the best way to secure these types of endpoints. 
If I use aws_iam to secure it does that mean that any user that hasn't signed up can not access the endpoint?
Or if I use cognito pool authorizers will I be able to distinguish from a logged in user and a non logged user?

Thanks, any help and additional explanations will be much appreciated.  I'm still trying to get my head around Cognito.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: if an endpoint returns different payloads depending on whether the user is signedup/loggedin, should this endpoint is secured (using AWS Cognito)?

We have two solution:

1. Solution 1: Define one endpoint. **This endpoint is not secured.** In the code of apigateway-integration , checking whether cognito authorizer is provided.

   - If "cognito authorizer" is provided (signed in user), returns data for signed in user
   - If "cognito authorizer" is NOT provided (NOT signed in user), returns data for visitor
2. Solution 2: Define three endpoints. One for receive initial request, one for returning data of visitor, one for returning data of signed in user:

   - Endpoint#1: Receive initial request, check whether cognito authorizer is provided <= **This endpoint is not secured.**

     - If "cognito authorizer" is provided (signed in user), redirect the request to Endpoint#2
     - If "cognito authorizer" is NOT provided (NOT signed in user), redirect the request to Endpoint#3
   - Endpoint#2: Returns data for signed in user <= **This endpoint is secured.**
   - Endpoint#3: Returns data for visitor <= **This endpoint is not secured.**

Summary: The endpoint for handling initial request should not be secured. Just consider secure for request/processing of returning signed-in/visitor user data.

Comment: I thought about this, but then i thought having an endpoint that is not secured would be a security risk.  Should this endpoint not be secured by oauth ? or does it not need to be secured at all ?

Comment: It doesn't need to be secured at all. I can't see any security risk in this case.

Comment: I found an even better solution after i took a longer look into cognito.  You can get an access key for the client and the user, and you can use either of those to query the endpoint.  Within the endpoint you can check whether the access key belongs to a user, or whether it belongs to a client.